# How to use bootstrap progress bars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a foolish question But I have no idea where to begin. 
I want to use Bootstrap's [Progress Bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).
I have a simple todo list app. I want to be able to visually show that 70% of a todo list is complete.

How would I go about this, or what resources do I need to look at. I can only find information on using the progress bars to display a websites loading progress.

I want to set these up to be dynamic of course. So when a user marks an object as complete, then the progress bar should change as well.

_todo_item.html.erb

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <% if todo_item.completed? %>
        <div class="complete">
            <%= link_to complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :patch do %>
                <i style="opacity: 0.4;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="todo_item">
            <p style="opacity: 0.4;"><strike><%= todo_item.content %></strike></p>
        </div>
        <div class="trash">
            <%= link_to todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="complete">
            <%= link_to complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :patch do %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="todo_item">
            <p><%= todo_item.content %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="trash">
            <%= link_to todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

todo_items_controller.rb

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_todo_list
    before_action :set_todo_item, except: [:create]

    def create
        @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.create(todo_item_params)
        redirect_to @todo_list
    end

    def destroy
        if @todo_item.destroy
            flash[:success] = "Todo List item was deleted"
        else
            flash[:error] = "Todo List item could not be deleted."
        end
        redirect_to @todo_list
    end

    def complete
        @todo_item.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
        redirect_to @todo_list, notice: "Todo item completed"
    end

    private

    def set_todo_list
        @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    end

    def set_todo_item
        @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    end

    def todo_item_params
        params[:todo_item].permit(:content)
    end

end
```

A users has a todo_list and a todo list has a todo_item. I want to use a progress bar so that I can show a percentage of tasks that have been completed.

Comment: Please explain what exactly the problem is you are experiencing? I am assuming you can just draw a progress bar? How do you mark a job as done? Using ajax? Can you show some code?

Comment: You can take help of Ajax calls to check how many tasks are complete and then set the `aria-valuenow="60"` attribute to the calculated result using jquery or basic javascript.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this example](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/17WOy63vYD), taken from the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-basic), you can see the width is set on the `.progress-bar` element. That width is what sets the 'completeness' of the bar. So for 70% done, set its width to 70%.

Relevant code from Bootstrap:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 60%;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks- I mean more like tying it to my database. For example i have 5 different todo lists. each one has maybe 10 items. I want to either show X/50 or X/10 as a progress bar. I just found a gem: http://chartkick.com/. This is more along the lines of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ted If **style="width: 60%;"** sets the displayed progress of the bar then what is the purpose of **aria-valuenow="60"**?

Comment: @Dercni sorry, it is a late answer but that `aria-valuenow="60"` is for accessibility purposes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap Progress Bar implementation for **HTML Forms**:

-This scripts creates an event handler.

-When the user switches input element (*form-group* in this case), it **increments the progress bar status by 20%**  (there are 5 inputs in my form).

```
 let progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0];

     $('.form-group').focusout(function() { 
        let currentValue = parseInt(progressBar.style['width']);
        progressBar.style['width']=currentValue+20+"%";
     });
```

[You can find some examples here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-progress-bars.php)